# Jquery checkbox filtering - repair

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, filtering

I have found a script with jquery filtering that i need. 
In that script some item have values of green and some of green and yellow. If you choose colors green and yellow, you get all green and yellow items, and items that are both green and yellow. 
I would need to change that so that if i choose green and yellow, i would only get item that are both green and yellow.

I'm not really good at js so i would really appreciate the help.

```
var byProperty = [], byColor = [], byLocation = [];

    $("input[name=fl-colour]").on( "change", function() {
        if (this.checked) byProperty.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
        else removeA(byProperty, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
    });

    $("input[name=fl-size]").on( "change", function() {
        if (this.checked) byColor.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
        else removeA(byColor, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
    });

    $("input[name=fl-cont]").on( "change", function() {
        if (this.checked) byLocation.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
        else removeA(byLocation, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
    });

    $("input").on( "change", function() {
        var str = "Include items \n";
        var selector = '', cselector = '', nselector = '';

        var $lis = $('.flowers > div'),
            $checked = $('input:checked');  

        if ($checked.length) {  

            if (byProperty.length) {        
                if (str == "Include items \n") {
                    str += "    " + "with (" +  byProperty.join(',') + ")\n";               
                    $($('input[name=fl-colour]:checked')).each(function(index, byProperty){
                        if(selector === '') {
                            selector += "[data-category~='" + byProperty.id + "']";                     
                        } else {
                            selector += ",[data-category~='" + byProperty.id + "']";    
                        }                
                    });                 
                } else {
                    str += "    AND " + "with (" +  byProperty.join(' OR ') + ")\n";                
                    $($('input[name=fl-size]:checked')).each(function(index, byProperty){
                        selector += "[data-category~='" + byProperty.id + "']";
                    });
                }                           
            }

            if (byColor.length) {                       
                if (str == "Include items \n") {
                    str += "    " + "with (" +  byColor.join(' OR ') + ")\n";                   
                    $($('input[name=fl-size]:checked')).each(function(index, byColor){
                        if(selector === '') {
                            selector += "[data-category~='" + byColor.id + "']";                    
                        } else {
                            selector += ",[data-category~='" + byColor.id + "']";   
                        }                
                    });                 
                } else {
                    str += "    AND " + "with (" +  byColor.join(' OR ') + ")\n";               
                    $($('input[name=fl-size]:checked')).each(function(index, byColor){
                        if(cselector === '') {
                            cselector += "[data-category~='" + byColor.id + "']";                   
                        } else {
                            cselector += ",[data-category~='" + byColor.id + "']";  
                        }                   
                    });
                }           
            }

            if (byLocation.length) {            
                if (str == "Include items \n") {
                    str += "    " + "with (" +  byLocation.join(' OR ') + ")\n";                
                    $($('input[name=fl-cont]:checked')).each(function(index, byLocation){
                        if(selector === '') {
                            selector += "[data-category~='" + byLocation.id + "']";                     
                        } else {
                            selector += ",[data-category~='" + byLocation.id + "']";    
                        }                
                    });             
                } else {
                    str += "    AND " + "with (" +  byLocation.join(' OR ') + ")\n";                
                    $($('input[name=fl-cont]:checked')).each(function(index, byLocation){
                        if(nselector === '') {
                            nselector += "[data-category~='" + byLocation.id + "']";                    
                        } else {
                            nselector += ",[data-category~='" + byLocation.id + "']";   
                        }   
                    });
                }            
            }

            $lis.hide(); 
            console.log(selector);
            console.log(cselector);
            console.log(nselector);

            if (cselector === '' && nselector === '') {         
                $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).show();
            } else if (cselector === '') {
                $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).filter(nselector).show();
            } else if (nselector === '') {
                $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).filter(cselector).show();
            } else {
                $('.flowers > div').filter(selector).filter(cselector).filter(nselector).show();
            }

        } else {
            $lis.show();
        }   

        $("#result").html(str); 

    });

    function removeA(arr) {
        var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
        while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
            what = a[--L];
            while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
                arr.splice(ax, 1);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3gf1j1ec/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would obtain an intersection of arrays. It uses the [`Array.prototype.every`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/every) method to produce the match.

```js
var byProperty = [], byColor = [], byLocation = [];
  
var intersectionOfColours = function(){
    
    //    get an array of the selected colours
    var selectedColours = $('form input[name="fl-colour"]:checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    
    //    iterate through the flowers and show/hide
    $('.flowers .flower').each(function(){
        var flowerColours = $(this).data("category").split(' ');
        //    if all selected colours can be found in flowerColours, we have a match
        var match = selectedColours.every(function(thisColour){
            return (flowerColours.indexOf(thisColour) !== -1);
        });
        if (match) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
    
    // debug
    $('#result').html( JSON.stringify(selectedColours) );
};

$("input[name=fl-colour]").on( "change", intersectionOfColours);
```

```css
label {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

.flowers-wrap {
    width: 100%;
}

.flowers-wrap form {
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
}

.flower {
    background-color: #DEE;
    padding: .5em;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.flowers {
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre id=result></pre>

<div class="flowers-wrap">
    
    <h3>Available Flowers</h3>
    <p><strong>Filter flowers by colour:</strong></p>
    <form>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="red" id="red" />Red</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="yellow" id="yellow" />Yellow</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="pink" id="pink" />Pink</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="purple" id="purple" />Purple</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="green" id="green" />Green</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="fl-colour" value="other" id="other" />Other</label>
    </form>
        
    <div class="flowers">
        <div class="flower" data-id="aloe" data-category="green small medium africa">Aloe</div>
        <div class="flower" data-id="lavendar" data-category="purple green medium africa europe">Lavender</div>
        <div class="flower" data-id="stinging-nettle" data-category="green large africa europe asia">Stinging Nettle</div>
        <div class="flower" data-id="gorse" data-category="green yellow large europe">Gorse</div>  
        <div class="flower" data-id="hemp" data-category="green large asia">Hemp</div>  
        <div class="flower" data-id="titan-arum" data-category="purple other giant asia">Titan Arum</div>  
        <div class="flower" data-id="golden-wattle" data-category="green yellow large australasia">Golden Wattle</div>  
        <div class="flower" data-id="purple-prairie-clover" data-category="purple green other medium north-america">Purple Prairie Clover</div> 
        <div class="flower" data-id="camellia" data-category="pink other large north-america">Camellia</div> 
        <div class="flower" data-id="scarlet-carnation" data-category="red medium north-america">Scarlet Carnation</div> 
        <div class="flower" data-id="indian-paintbrush" data-category="red medium north-america">Indian Paintbrush</div>  
        <div class="flower" data-id="moss-verbena" data-category="purple other small south-america">Moss Verbena</div>  
        <div class="flower" data-id="climbing-dayflower" data-category="blue tiny south-america">Climbing Dayflower</div>  
        <div class="flower" data-id="antarctic-pearlwort" data-category="green yellow large antarctica">Antarctic Pearlwort</div>                  
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Tnx dude, that's exactly what i need.

Comment: Any tips on how to implement that code into exsisting one?

Comment: first of all, start with cleaner, well structured markup, so you can find your way around more easily. second, i would move each *type* of property into it's own `data-whatever` attribute. (ex: `<div data-size="medium" data-colour="green" data-region="africa europe">`). Finally, create three functions (i've created the first) and call all three every time a form value changes by binding to the event like this: `$("input").on("change", callAllThreeFunctions )`