# How to live filter results with jQuery in "AND" like manner

Tags: jquery, html

Could you please advice how to filter with the jQuery in "AND" like manner or intersection? To return true ONLY when all of the criteria are met. I have several checkboxes and need to show only that products that match exactly all of the selected checkboxes.

I have found the following code, but it is like "OR" condition for the filter.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.category').on('change', function(){
      var category_list = [];
      $('#filters :input:checked').each(function(){
        var category = $(this).val();
        category_list.push(category);
      });

      if(category_list.length == 0)
        $('.product').fadeIn();
      else {
        $('.product').each(function(){
          var item = $(this).attr('data-tag');
          var itemarr = item.split(',');
          $this = $(this);
          var showItem=false;
          $.each(itemarr,function(ind,val){
            if(jQuery.inArray(val,category_list) > -1){

              $this.fadeIn('slow');
              return false;
            }
            else
              $this.hide();
          });
        });
      }   
    });
  });
```

Comment: Which part specifically are you saying is functioning like an or?  The `inArray` part?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Taplar, yes, exactly the `inArray` part

Comment: I found a solution here [intersection of arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27204253/2262978)